# Getting a run time error in the Linked List operation of deleting a specific element from the List

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list

I know that the Create and Display operations are working perfectly fine. But there is something wrong with the delete operation which I'm not able to understand. I have rectified the logic and it seems perfect to me. Please help.
I have tried debugger tool from the IDE but it's not giving any helpful response either!
Suppose a create a new list. It will ask me for number of nodes and data. Lets say that I create 3 nodes with data 3, 5 and 7.
Now if I display it, then "3 5 7" will be printed.
Now if I want to delete the value 5 so that "3 7" will be printed, I will use the delete function and pass the value 5. But it is not happening. While run time, the program freezes without giving me any error or cursor to continue typing.

```
void List::deleteinbtw(int num)
{
    Node *temp=listptr, *temp1;;

    if(listptr==NULL)
        cout << "/nList is Empty!\n";

    else if(temp->data==num)
    {
        listptr=listptr->next;
        delete temp;
    }

    else
    {
        while(temp->next!=NULL)
        {
            if(temp->next->data==num)
            {
                temp1=temp->next;
                temp->next=temp1->next;
                delete temp1;
            }
        }
        temp=temp->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: Minimal examples please. We are lazy and don't want to read a lot of code.

Comment: Please be more specific than "there is something wrong". What are you inputting, what should the program do, what does it actually do?

Comment: @molbdnilo the delete function is supposed to search for the number in the list and delete it!

Comment: @RajanPandey Relevant content should be **edit**ed into the question.

Comment: @RajanPandey Yes, but what is the problem with it and what is your test case? We're not going to invent test cases and run your program to figure out.

Comment: I think you'll find the problem if you assume that the deleting loop is wrong and read it carefully line by line, thinking about what each line does. (Pay very close attention to the braces.)

Comment: I edited it out.

Comment: [`using namespace std;` is a bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/2176813), never use it.

Comment: I see
Thanks for the info @tambre

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
void List::deleteinbtw(int num)
```

{
    Node *temp=listptr, *temp1;

```
if(listptr==NULL)
    cout << "/nList is Empty!\n";

else if(temp->data==num)
{
    listptr=listptr->next;
    delete temp;
}

else
{
    while(temp->next!=NULL)
    {
        if(temp->next->data==num)
        {
            temp1=temp->next;
            temp->next=temp1->next;
            delete temp1;
            break;
        }
        temp=temp->next;
    }

}
```

}

Comment: are you sure? it works on me..  i added break .. and put the         
 temp=temp->next inside the while loop..